# React how to print landscape / portrait for different components

Tags: css, reactjs, printing

Our React app has ~10 different routes and we'd like for them all to be printable. We're using the css print media query to clean styles up for print, and the frontend has a button that calls `window.print()` on click.

Amongst the 10 routes, 7 of the pages look better with `landscape` whereas the other 3 are better as `portrait`. Currently, `@page` is only set once, in the app's top-level `App.scss` file.

**App.scss**

```
@page {
  size: portrait;
}

@media print and (orientation: portrait) {
  .table-cols {
      max-width: 50%;
  }

  .my-selects { display: none; }
  .my-print-button { display: none; }
  .my-footer { display: none; }
  ...
}
```

How (if at all) can the `@page { size: portrait }` be switched to landscape certain routes, depending on the route? Maybe a `landscape` class and a `portrait` class could be made, that each set their own `@page` value, and then the classes would be used on the elements the routes are returning?

Comment: did you try the approach you're proposing? it sounds reasonable

Comment: i did without luck, however I came up with a different solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function setPageSize(cssPageSize) {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = `@page {size: ${cssPageSize}}`;
    style.id = 'page-orientation';
    document.head.appendChild(style);
}

function PrintIcon({ teamId, orientation = 'portrait' }) {
    // Set orientation of page being printed
    useEffect(() => {
        setPageSize(orientation);
        return () => {
            const child = document.getElementById('page-orientation');
            child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        };
    }, [orientation]);

    return (
        <div className='print-button' onClick={() => window.print()}>
            Click to Print
        </div>
    );
}

export default PrintIcon;
```

the `useEffect` calls the `setPageSize()` function which manually adds the `@page` to the head, and its cleanup function removes the `@page`...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="printLayoutContainer">
     <style type="text/css" media="print">
         {" @page { size: portrait; } "}
       </style>
</div>
```

You can use internal CSS to print landscape or portrait.

Comment: Even though this might work, it's not valid html to put a style element outside the head section.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a nice way to do this dynamically using CSS variables.

CSS

```css
:root {
    --orientation: portrait;
}
   
@media print {
    @page {
        size: A4 var(--orientation);
    }
}
```

JS

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--orientation', 'landscape');
```